# writing matlab cell array to a text file

Tags: matlab

i have huffman encoded some data like

dict = huffmandict(symbols,p).

the values of dict are as following.

```
[-21]    [1x9  double]
[-20]    [1x9  double]
[-19]    [1x8  double]
[-18]    [1x9  double]
[-17]    [1x9  double]
[-16]    [1x9  double]
[-15]    [1x9  double]
[-14]    [1x9  double]
[-13]    [1x9  double]
[-12]    [1x8  double]
[-11]    [1x9  double]
[-10]    [1x9  double]
[ -9]    [1x9  double]
[ -8]    [1x8  double]
[ -7]    [1x8  double]
[ -6]    [1x8  double]
[ -5]    [1x7  double]
[ -4]    [1x6  double]
[ -3]    [1x6  double]
[ -2]    [1x5  double]
[ -1]    [1x3  double]
[  0]    [          0]
[  1]    [1x3  double]
[  2]    [1x5  double]
[  3]    [1x6  double]
[  4]    [1x6  double]
[  5]    [1x7  double]
[  6]    [1x7  double]
[  7]    [1x7  double]
[  8]    [1x7  double]
[  9]    [1x8  double]
[ 10]    [1x8  double]
[ 11]    [1x8  double]
[ 12]    [1x8  double]
[ 13]    [1x8  double]
[ 14]    [1x8  double]
[ 15]    [1x8  double]
[ 16]    [1x9  double]
[ 17]    [1x9  double]
[ 18]    [1x8  double]
[ 19]    [1x9  double]
[ 20]    [1x10 double]
[ 21]    [1x10 double]
[ 22]    [1x11 double]
[ 23]    [1x10 double]
[ 24]    [1x10 double]
[ 25]    [1x10 double]
[ 26]    [1x10 double]
[ 27]    [1x11 double]
[ 28]    [1x10 double]
```

now i want to write this dict to a text file and later on retrieve it from the same text file during the decoding.i tried using `dlmwrite()` function but it does not work.kindly tell me how can i write this data to a text file and later retrieve it in the same format.thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not going to edit your code and remove the `[1x9 double]` etc to make your code work. It would be much better if you added the code that generated that `dict`. People can run that code, produce a real `dict` and work with that. You will have a much higher chance of getting a useful answer if you do. see [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help.

Comment: Why don't you just store the data in a MAT-file? `save('dict.mat', 'dict')` to save, `load('dict.mat')` to load.

Comment: dict has been generated through built in matlab function.

Comment: @dasdingonesin let us hope that OP have a good reason to store it in a textfile. @nainaSony You can always store it with `;` as a separator. Use `fprintf` to do the writing. Remember to use `fopen` and `fclose` before and after writing.

Comment: dear sir, can you kindly give me a sample code?not much experienced with matlab.

Comment: @nainasony In that case I would need to know the wanted format. How do you mean to read the data?

Comment: in a text file in any format provided that i be able to read the text file in the same format.